# Wait for delayed/asynchronous functions to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I'm building a jQuery-based library that has a number of custom events fire on an element (beforeShow, show, afterShow, beforeHide, hide, afterHide).

The user will be able to define their own functions that run when these functions are fired.  However, due to the fact they may involve animation or asynchronous requests, I can't simply trigger all the *show events (for example) one after the other.  Currently I'm making it a requirement that any custom functions have to trigger the next event.

So, if the user defines their own function to run when `beforeShow` is triggered, that function must then trigger the `show` event, which must then trigger the `afterShow` event.

This isn't ideal and I was wondering if there is any way for me to wait for the function to finish without the user having to trigger the next event manually.  I was looking at `$.Deferred`, but that requires returning of a Deferred object which, for the purposes of imposing on my users, is no better.

Comment: just to clarify, you are already using a callback function after animation is complete? The only way I know how to do this would be to have a self-invoking function that plays the next animation according to which animation has just completed.

Comment: There is no callback function being provided by my library.  The user's custom function might provide a callback to their own animation though. A function doesn't call the next animation per se.  It triggers an event on an element.  That element may have another function bound to that newly fired event that does the next animation.